# Is it legal to build same website like amazon

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property, website

I would like to know Is it legal to build same website like amazon or any other website's by copying there features.

**Example:**

I am planning to use amazon as requirement gathering source for my `eCommerce` project.

I would go to [amazon.com](http://amazon.com/) and note down all there features and UI design etc, then I would start building website from scratch using the requirement gathered.

**Note:**

I will not exactly copy the websites design. But only features like Cash On Delivery, Online Payments, Recently Viewed Products etc.

I would like to know how could one gather requirements without looking at competitors or How to get any idea without searching ?

Didn't all similar websites got the requirement's by looking at competitors ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not illegal to make a competing ecommerce site.

What might be illegal is copying the specific details of Amazon.

You should read the primer on copyright on this site (and if someone could link that here and edit this parenthetical out, I would appreciate it, but I don't know where it is nor how Stack software does links) for more information.

Your specific method of requirements development seems like it might open up some vectors of argument in such an infringement case.

Additionally, there *may* be patent issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I would like to know how could one gather requirements without looking at competitors ?

Comment: @stom: Feel free to look at competitors' sites. You can do the same thing a million different ways (unless it's patented, but that is becoming less and less of a worry as prior art accumulates). It's when you copy code, or the "look and feel" of the site, that you're likely to run into issues.